# How can I delete whole SQLAlchemy databases on my Mac computer?

Tags: macos, sqlite

I realize that I have far too many databases stored on my MacBook Pro. In most of my files, I initialize databases through:

> app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/UNIQUE_NAME'

However, I cannot seem to access this directory, and searching for the `tmp` folder in Spotlight doesn't return the folder I am looking for. So, how can I go about accessing this folder and delete some of the databases it contains. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an OS X question, but in OS X, go to the Finder, choose the Go menu, and then choose Go to Folder.  Then type '/tmp' as the folder to go to.

You should be able to see your databases and delete from there.

FWIW, you can create SQLlite databases anywhere - for example, create a "db" folder in your Documents directory and then use this as configuration:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////Users/you/Documents/db/UNIQUE_NAME'
```

That way it'll be much easier to clear out your dbs after you're done with them.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you. And thank you for the tip about saving dbs in easier to access computer folders– much appreciated.